# iPad CSS3 webkitTransform and touch events - a slight unexplained stutter

Tags: ipad, html, css, webkit, css-transitions

This is pertaining to an image gallery, so as you "swipe", images are loaded and unloaded off of the screen, but the center image always appears smoothly.

It is code derived from the swipeview library described here: http://cubiq.org/swipeview

The problem is that, there is a 100-200ms delay which occurs between when the javascript sets the webkitTransform in the touch end event, and when the element actually starts animating on the screen.

This problematic delay, only happens intermittently; it seems that it starts happening consistently after about 15-20 slides have been unloaded/loaded.

In the touch move event there is code like this:

```
element.style.webkitTransitionDuration = 0
element.style.webkitTransform = "translate3d( etc. ) "
```

And this functions very fast, such that if you move your finger around on the ipad, the element follows your finger precisely and "instantly".

And in the touch end event there is code like this:

```
element.style.webkitTransitionDuration = '<some_number>ms';
element.style.webkitTransform = "translate3d( etc. ) "
```

And the touch end event is where the problem is.  The touch End event itself fires the instant the finger is removed from the ipad, however, when the problem is happening, the css update doesnt trigger an actual animation on screen until after the problematic delay mentioned above.

Comment: I'm working on this same exact problem. What's weird is that if you test the time lapse between the last touchmove event and the touchend event, it's always around 30ms. I'm using the strategy of updating X and Y on an animation rig, and then in requestAnimationFrame, I bind that rig to the DOM element.

It's perfectly smooth during touchmove and perfectly smooth after touchend, but it stutters in between. I tried re-writing my code exactly like at http://cubiq.org/swipeview, where it uses CSS for transitions, not requestAnimation frame, and yet it still has the same hiccup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a tricky one. I finally found the culprit. In my touchend event listener, I was calling a function that added classes to DOM elements. This caused Safari to take a moment to rewire textures to the GPU, resulting in the stutter. Removing those direct className updates made it all buttery smooth again (and I'm still using requestAnimationFrame and not CSS transitions).

I moved my className changes to a separate event that fired from touchend instead and it didn't cause any performance issues. So, if you must set classes, just don't do it directly in the touchend callback. Trigger another event instead or set the classes in requestAnimationFrame.

Comment: Actually, on my iPhone 4, it still stutters a bit between the last touchmove event and the touchend event, but it still animates within that stutter, instead of sticking in the same spot. It's buttery on my iPad 2 though.

Comment: This is late, but I thought I should mention that in my case the culprit was very similar - in the touchEnd event I was adding classes to DOM elements.

Comment: When you say "trigger another event instead" do you mean you have 2 touchend listener functions? Or that in the touchend callback you say $document.trigger('someEvent') and attach the class changes to that? If you could clarify would be really helpful as I'm having a similar problem... cheers

Comment: In the end I figured it out. In my touchend handler I triggered another event that I made up, passing through the original event parameter to this handler. Then in the handler for the new event I performed all the touchend logic. This caused the delay on touchend to disappear. Magic! Thanks!